# jquery getJSON based on selected option

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I want to make a getJSON search based on the selected option. For instance: if I choose Italian in the select option menu I want the getJSON query to look like json.w1.Italian.

I know that this code is not correct, that's why I'm asking for help.

Here's the code:

```
<select name="language">
    <option selected="selected" value="english">English</option>
    <option value="german">German</option>
    <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
    <option value="italian">Italian</option>
    <option value="french">French</option>
    <option value="portuguese">Portuguese</option>
    <option value="dutch">Dutch</option>
    <option value="romanian">Romanian</option>
    <option value="greek">Grek</option>
    <option value="bulgarian">Bulgarian</option>
</select>
<div id="language"></div>

<div id="results"></div>

<script>
    $("select")
        .change(function() {
            var str = "";
            $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
            });
            $("#language").text(str);

            var query = json.w1.str;

            $.getJSON("lang.json", function(json) {
                $("#results").text(query);
            });
        })
        .change();
</script>
```

Comment: Not really get what you mean. Are you mean that your json.w1 have attributes like `json.w1.dutch`, `json.w1.greek`, `json.w1.english`, etc and you want to get the value based on user selection? If that want you want, then you can use `var query = json.w1[str];`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a lot more complex than it needs to be - to get the chosen value of a `select` you can simply call `val()`. Then you can use bracket notation to retrieve an item from an object using the key as a string. Try this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var lang = $(this).val();
    $("#language").text(lang);
    $.getJSON('lang.json', function(json) {
        $('#results').text(json.w1[lang]);
    });
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you seem to have alot of code you dont need in your example. Without seeing your result json I think you want something like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/vpeLq3k4/

```
$( "select" )
    .change(function () {
    var lang = $( "select option:selected" ).val();
    $( "#language" ).text( lang );
    $.getJSON( "lang.json", function( json ) {
        $( "#results" ).text( json.w1.lang );
    });
});
```

If you post an example of what json is returned we can probably help a little more.

Comment: If I choose Spanish in my HTML code I want to print Casa for instance. Here is a short example of my JSON file:

    { 
        "w1":{"English":"House", "German":"Haus", "Spanish":"Casa"}
    }